# Webpack lint tests and source files

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I have the following webpack configuration which works fine except my unit tests, in the form `src/file.test.js`, are not being linted.  My other source files are linted correctly though.  I assume it is because my entry is index.js, which does not import any of the tests.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  },
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

How do I tell webpack to lint my `src/file.test.js` files?

Using webpack 3.7.1

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with webpack 4 :-( I couldn't find any solution. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not that pretty but you can do it by globing all test files as an entry point;

```
entry: {
    'main-main-code': ['src/entry.ts', ...]),
    'tests': glob.sync('./**/*.test.ts')
},
```